# Vue.js unknown custom element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm a beginner with Vue.js and I'm trying to create an app that caters my daily tasks and I ran into Vue Components. So below is what I've tried but unfortunately, it gives me this error:

> vue.js:1023 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you
>   register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure
>   to provide the "name" option.

Any ideas, help, please?

```js
new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  data : {
    tasks : [
      { name : "task 1", completed : false},
      { name : "task 2", completed : false},
      { name : "task 3", completed : true}
    ]
  },
  methods : {
  
  },
  computed : {
  
  },
  ready : function(){

  }

});

Vue.component('my-task',{
  template : '#task-template',
  data : function(){
    return this.tasks
  },
  props : ['task']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="task in tasks">
      <my-task :task="task"></my-task>
  </div>
  
</div>

<template id="task-template">
  <h1>My tasks</h1>
  <div class="">{{ task.name }}</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 136, accepted):

You forgot about the `components` section in your `Vue initialization`. So Vue actually doesn't know about your component.

Change it to:

```
var myTask = Vue.component('my-task', {
 template: '#task-template',
 data: function() {
  return this.tasks; //Notice: in components data should return an object. For example "return { someProp: 1 }"
 },
 props: ['task']
});

new Vue({
 el: '#app',
 data: {
  tasks: [{
    name: "task 1",
    completed: false
   },
   {
    name: "task 2",
    completed: false
   },
   {
    name: "task 3",
    completed: true
   }
  ]
 },
 components: {
  myTask: myTask
 },
 methods: {

 },
 computed: {

 },
 ready: function() {

 }

});
```

And here is jsBin, where all seems to works correctly: http://jsbin.com/lahawepube/edit?html,js,output

**UPDATE**

Sometimes you want your components to be globally visible to other components.

In this case you need to register your components in this way, before your `Vue initialization` or `export` (in case if you want to register component from the other component)

```
Vue.component('exampleComponent', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue')); //component name should be in camel-case
```

After you can add your component inside your `vue el`:

```
<example-component></example-component>
```

Comment: So If I have many components, I should then bind it on the components array?

Comment: @CodeDemon for sure. You can make it shorter if you will use `ES6`, like so `components: {myTask},` Or if its some small component, you can create it inside `components` property. But it seems like not good way, because of app scale.

Comment: Any ideas why I have this Vue warning : vue.js:1023 [Vue warn]: data functions should return an object. (found in component: <my-task>)?

Comment: you need to write it like so in components:

`data: function() { return { property1: 1, property2: 2 } }`

Comment: for my case, I had spelled components incorrectly as component. hence, I got this error.

Answer (score 65):

Just define `Vue.component()` before `new vue()`.

```
Vue.component('my-task',{
     .......
});

new Vue({
    .......
});
```

**update**

- HTML converts `<anyTag>`  to `<anytag>`
- So don't use captital letters for component's name
- Instead of `<myTag>` use `<my-tag>`

Github issue : https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/2308

Comment: This should be the main answer to the problem. I can confirm from the [vuejs docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html) and by trying it that Vue.component should be placed *before* the root (or `new Vue({})`).

Answer (score 5):

I just spared 1 hour with this message - usually easy to solve.

I got this error because I forgot to close my <script> tag in the parent component.

The browser console & my code editor gave no indication unfortunately.

Comment: mine is the dumbest, I put the component outside the #app element that's why it keep saying "component not found"

Comment: Thanks kind stranger,i spent like 3 hours on this and you saved my time.

Answer (score 4):

Don't overuse `Vue.component()`, it registers components globally. You can create file, name it MyTask.vue, export there Vue object
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html
and then import in your main file, and don't forget to register it:

```
new Vue({
...
components: { myTask }
...
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Vue definitely has some bugs around this. I find that although registering a component like so

```
components: { MyComponent }
```

will work most of the time, and can be used as MyComponent or my-component automatically, sometimes you have to spell it out as such

```
components: { 'my-component' : MyComponent }
```

And use it strictly as my-component

Answer (score 4):

In my case I had
`import {component} from "@/path/to/component.vue"`

Changing it to
`import component from "@/path/to/component.vue"`
fixed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

This solved it for me: I supplied a third argument being an object.

in `app.js` (working with laravel and webpack):

```
Vue.component('news-item', require('./components/NewsItem.vue'), {
    name: 'news-item'
});
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, this error may seem obvious, but one day I was looking for an answer JUST TO FOUND OUT THAT I HAD **2 times COMPONENTS** declared. it was driving me nuts as VueJS does not complain at all when you declare it 2 times, obvious I had a lot of code in between, and when I added a new component, I placed the declaration in the top, while I also had one close to the bottom. So next time looks for this first, saves a lot of time

Comment: I save kind of same problems.    I use a image manager in OrchardCore.Midia, and on the same page, I include vue using <script src="..."></script.   Vue not work until I remove vue from the image manager. One day, I include BootstrapVue in the same page, it not work and report `Unknown custom element: <b-alert> ` until I remove vuedraggable from the image manager.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that you have added the component to the components.

For example:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {}
},
components: {
    'lead-status-modal': LeadStatusModal,
},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was following along the Vue documentation at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/index.html when I ran into this issue.

Later they clarify the syntax:

> So far, we’ve only registered components globally, using Vue.component:
>
> ```
>    Vue.component('my-component-name', {
>        // ... options ...
>    })
> ```
>
> Globally registered **components can be used in the template of any root**
> **Vue instance (new Vue) created afterwards** – and even inside all >subcomponents of that Vue instance’s component tree.

(https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Organizing-Components)

So as Umesh Kadam says above, just make sure the global component definition comes before the `var app = new Vue({})` instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to create a component in vue.

```
let template = `<ul>
  <li>Your data here</li>
</ul>`;

Vue.component('my-task', {
  template: template,
  data() {

  },
  props: {
    task: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {

  },
  ready() {

  }
});

new Vue({
 el : '#app'
});
```