# [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <testimonial-photo-inner>

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have just installed VueJS on my website and I'm getting tonnes of console errors like the one above. I am not trying to create any Vue components (yet) but my website does contain a number of custom HTML tags.

Does Vue treat any custom HTML tage (e.g. not one in the HTML spec) as something it needs to compile and will it always complain about tags it doesn't recognise?

Is it possible to switch theses warning off?

Please note: This is not a duplicate of [Vue js unknown custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element)

The user there is actually trying to create a Vue component.

Comment: The more I think about this the more I think this is a crazy design decision for Vue. It should only parse elements it knows about, not every single custom element except ones you specifically ignore. You don't have to tell Angular what to ignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [ignoreElements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements) configuration parameter to have Vue ignore elements that it should not touch.

So in your code you would likely want to add:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'testimonial-photo-inner'
]
```

And include any other tags you might be using that you do not want Vue to touch.