# Registering a Vue JS component

Tags: javascript, google-maps, import, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a JS page with Vue Js instance, in which I am importing a component. However I am receiving the following error:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component
>   correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name"
>   option.

The **name** attribute is correct in the **export object** of the component I am importing so I am wondering what is causing this error.

Component:

```
<template>
  <GoogleMapLoader :mapConfig="mapConfig" apiKey="YOUR_API_KEY">
    <template slot-scope="{ google, map }">
      <GoogleMapMarker
        v-for="marker in markers"
        :key="marker.id"
        :marker="marker"
        :google="google"
        :map="map"
      />
      <GoogleMapLine
        v-for="line in lines"
        :key="line.id"
        :path.sync="line.path"
        :google="google"
        :map="map"
      />
    </template>
  </GoogleMapLoader>
</template>

<script>
import GoogleMapLoader from "./GoogleMapLoader";
import GoogleMapMarker from "./GoogleMapMarker";
import GoogleMapLine from "./GoogleMapLine";
import { mapSettings } from "./mapSettings";

export default {
  name: "TravelMap",
  components: {
    GoogleMapLoader,
    GoogleMapMarker,
    GoogleMapLine
  },

  data() {
    return {
      markers: [
        { id: "here", position: { lat: 32.800359, lng: -117.021605 } },
        { id: "there", position: { lat: -51.628489, lng: -72.545818 } }
      ],
      lines: [{
        id: "1",
        path: [{ lat: 32.800359, lng: -117.021605 }, { lat: -51.628489, lng: -72.545818 }]
      }]
    };
  },

  computed: {
    mapConfig() {
      return {
        ...mapSettings,
        center: this.mapCenter
      };
    },

    mapCenter() {
      return this.markers[1].position;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

---

```
import Vue from "vue";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

import TravelMap from "./TravelMap";

new Vue({
  el: "#App",
  components: { TravelMap }
});
```

Here is also a sandbox link with the the entire code sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/yqqwwz0z1x

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vue.js unknown custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element)

Comment: Not the same answer. I am importing the component before the vue instance and I have the components section inside the Vue initialization.

Comment: `<travel-map class="travel-map"/> ` In HTML, capital word in not allowed, instead you should used kebab Case. Also rename your google components, it should be `<google-map-loader> ` and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing it to load the component using **Laravel** instead:

```
Vue.component('google-map', require('../GoogleMaps/GoogleMap').default);

new Vue({
  el: "#App"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in one of the comments, captial words are not allowed in HTML.

Your first option would be to just change your TravelMap tag in index.html to `<travel-map class="travel-map" />`

Another option would be to change the Vue Instance creation.

If you change the body content from your index.html file to

`<body>
     <div id="app" />
     <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
 </body>`

and create your Vue instace like this

`new Vue({
   el: "#app",
   template: "<App/>",
   components: { App }
 });`

the App.vue will be your application entry, and inside the App's template you will be able to use the same name as used to import/register the component.

Link to the updated sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/50vo260nqp

Comment: I understand that uppercase HTML tags are not allowed, however having them uppercase does not affect the file fro working. In your updated sandbox that is functional it is still working with uppercase. I also understand that adding app.vue as the entry point like you have done so would get it working, however the whole point of this problem was to simplify the example and  get it to work without the extra file inclusion.

Comment: @McWayWeb Changing your application entry to the app.vue component is just that you dont have problems like that.
Theres a difference between the index.html file and the <template> tag in components.

You cant refer to your component using the uppercase name there. You have to use kebab-case.
In the template part of your components you can use the same name as you used to register the component, e.g. `TravelMap`