# Compile Laravel Vue components into different js files

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-5, vue-component

I have a big project in Laravel, which have several front-ends, depending on logged user.

I also have a `shared` directory, where common components (like table, modal, etc.) can be used by the different front-end.

I want to compile each front-end to a different js file, so I can include only the relevant file for each user.

**What I have till now:**

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/frontendUser.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/frontendAdmin.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

Under `resources/js` I have a separate file for each front-end, for example `frontendAdmin.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component(
    'frontend-admin-component',
    require('./components/FrontendAdminComponent.vue').default
);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

When I run `npm run dev` fiels are compiled correctly, and I can include them from the blade file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/frontendAdmin.js') }}" defer></script>
```

However, I get in console this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <frontend-admin-component>
 - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components,
 make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Looks like the component behaves well, however I assume the warning exists for some reason and would like to fix it.

Is what I try to do have sense? What is wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue.js unknown custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element)

Comment: I followed this issue @thisiskelvin, but it does not solve my problem.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution? If you find a solution please post this solution.

Comment: Hi, in my case, (I was blind) the problem was solved after I've put the ```<script src="{{ mix('js/dashboard.js') }}"></script>``` in the right place. Between ```@section('scripts') ... @endsection``` in the blade file.

Answer (score 0):

This warning generally occurs if you do not specify any name your component

For example, if you have a component called `User.vue` then your component should be as follows:

```
<template>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 name: 'User'
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

This name option is not mandatory but it is convention to use a name for each component for all components.