# Vue single file component error template element not found or is empty

Tags: vue.js

I have very simple single file component, defined in checkbox-wrapper.vue:

```
<template id="checkbox-wrapper">
  <div class="checkbox-wrapper" @click="check">
    <div :class="{ checkbox: true, checked: checked }"></div>
    <div class="title">{{ title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      checked: false,
      title: "Check me"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    check() {
      this.checked = !this.checked;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I've had successfully build this component with webpack to checkbox-wrapper.js.

Here is app1.js:

```
Vue.component('checkbox-wrapper',{
  template: "#checkbox-wrapper"
});



var app1 = new Vue({
  el: "#app1",
  data: {},
  methods: {}
});
```

And index.html, where I've tried to show this component:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Empty project</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="checkbox-wrapper.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app1">
            <checkbox-wrapper></checkbox-wrapper>
        </div>

        <script src="app1.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am receiving errors:

> [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #checkbox-wrapper
>
> [Vue warn]: Template element not found or is empty: #checkbox-wrapper
>
> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong - component is included and registered before initialization of vue. I was following advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element), but it's not working for me.

Comment: If you have a single-file component, you should import it for use in local registration. See the _"ES2015 modules"_ example here ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration

Comment: I am really struggling with this - can you please provide working example.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach seems strange to me.

> I was following advice from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element)

But your setup is via webpack, it's different from him, he was using the [cdn approach](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#CDN), he mounted vue component directly to an HTML element whose id in an actual HTML page (not just id of a vue template). This is the approach usually for small testing projects btw, those don't care about performance.

About setting up a project, If not really needed, just use the [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) instead of config webpack yourself. [The instructuion](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html) is pretty awesome so I believe you'll easily make it work.

Answer (score -1):

What solved my problem:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import firstComp from "./first-component";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    "first-component": firstComp
  }
});
```

That file must be transpiled, than transpiled .js included inside html and it's ok using this syntax:

```
<div id="app">
      <first-component></first-component>
</div>
```