# Add Vue-Component in existing Homepage with script type="module"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently using VueJS on an exiting Flask (Server-rendered) Homepage. I want to import a VueJS Component with the script-tag. The VueJS-Component should access to an API-Function from a third JS-file. The Cue-Component-File looks like this:

```
import {getContactsForNewMessageAPI} from "../../api/contactsAPI";

Vue.component('new-message-modal', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            selectFieldOptions: [],
            //... further attributes
        }
    },
    methods: {
        async getContacts(){
            this.selectFieldOptions = await getContactsForNewMessageAPI();
        },
        //... further methods
    }
});
```

### Option 1:

In a template file I'm able to import a VueJS-Component like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/newMessageVueComponent.js"></script>
```

But if I import the component with the type="text/javascript", I can't use a function from an extra api.js file inside of the component like this:

```js
import {getContactsForNewMessageAPI} from "../../api/contactsAPI";
```

The console prints the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

### Option 2

Second option I tried is to import the component with type="module" like this:

```js
<script type="module" src="js/ui/newMessageVueComponent.js"></script>
```

So I'm able to use the `getContactsForNewMessageAPI()` function, but the VueJS-component won't be rendered anymore. The following error occurs:

> Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.

Has anyone a solution for this?

Comment: You need a build system which will package all your frontend code and then you can import it via `option 1`

Comment: is there no other way except packing all my js-stuff with e.g. Webpack?

Comment: Nope. In my opinion using a build system makes the process a lot more smoother.

Comment: You either define the component before `Vue` initialization, or include the component inside `Vue` initialization.

Comment: @ChristosLytras the component is defined before VueJS is initialized

Comment: Option2 seems legit. Likely in your modal template you have included components which are not registered? can you provide the rest of implem of ```new-message-modal``` (not the methods but rather the components property and the template property)?

Comment: @MarcoWeber according to this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element) that is the culprit of the Option 2 error.