# Unknown custom element: <ckeditor> - did you register the component correctly?

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

I'm following the documentation for setting up a custom Vue ckeditor5 build in a Nuxt app. I created a custom build using the online builder (https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/), then downloaded it to my project.

Here is my CKEditorNuxt.vue file:

```
<template>
<div id="app">
    <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="editorData" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
</div>
</template>
<script>
  import Editor from '../ckeditor5-custom-editor/build/ckeditor.js';
  export default {
      name: 'CkeditorNuxt',
      data() {
          return {
              editor: Editor,
              editorData: '<p>Default text</p>',
              editorConfig: {
              }
          };
      }
  }
</script>
```

And inside where I'd like to place my template:

```
<CkeditorNuxt v-model="subsection.content"></CkeditorNuxt>
```

My custom build ckeditor.js file:

```
import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic/src/classiceditor.js';
import Autoformat from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat/src/autoformat.js';
import Base64UploadAdapter from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/src/adapters/base64uploadadapter.js';
import BlockQuote from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote/src/blockquote.js';
import Bold from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/bold.js';
import CloudServices from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-cloud-services/src/cloudservices.js';
import Essentials from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials/src/essentials.js';
import Heading from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading/src/heading.js';
import Image from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/image.js';
import ImageCaption from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagecaption.js';
import ImageStyle from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagestyle.js';
import ImageToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imagetoolbar.js';
import ImageUpload from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image/src/imageupload.js';
import Indent from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent/src/indent.js';
import Italic from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles/src/italic.js';
import Link from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link/src/link.js';
import List from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list/src/list.js';
import MediaEmbed from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-media-embed/src/mediaembed.js';
import Paragraph from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph/src/paragraph.js';
import PasteFromOffice from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office/src/pastefromoffice.js';
import Table from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/table.js';
import TableToolbar from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table/src/tabletoolbar.js';
import TextTransformation from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing/src/texttransformation.js';

class Editor extends ClassicEditor {}

Editor.builtinPlugins = [
    Autoformat,
    Base64UploadAdapter,
    BlockQuote,
    Bold,
    CloudServices,
    Essentials,
    Heading,
    Image,
    ImageCaption,
    ImageStyle,
    ImageToolbar,
    ImageUpload,
    Indent,
    Italic,
    Link,
    List,
    MediaEmbed,
    Paragraph,
    PasteFromOffice,
    Table,
    TableToolbar,
    TextTransformation
];

// Editor configuration.
Editor.defaultConfig = {
    toolbar: {
        items: [
            'heading',
            '|',
            'bold',
            'italic',
            'link',
            'bulletedList',
            'numberedList',
            '|',
            'outdent',
            'indent',
            '|',
            'imageUpload',
            'blockQuote',
            'insertTable',
            'mediaEmbed',
            'undo',
            'redo'
        ]
    },
    language: 'en',
    image: {
        toolbar: [
            'imageTextAlternative',
            'imageStyle:inline',
            'imageStyle:block',
            'imageStyle:side'
        ]
    },
    table: {
        contentToolbar: [
            'tableColumn',
            'tableRow',
            'mergeTableCells'
        ]
    }
};

export default Editor;
```

When I load the page, I get this error:
[image]

Why might this error be occurring? From other similar posts ([Vue.js unknown custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39382032/vue-js-unknown-custom-element)), I believe I should add an item to the components section, e.g.

```
  components: {
    ckeditor: Editor.component,
  }
```

as this works when I use the default CKEditor, but not for my custom build. I think this is the source of my error, but I'm not sure what the correct format is. How should I go about fixing this error? Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing a similar issue. Can anyone help ?